# Efficient way to delete multiple rows in sp with one call

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The below query returns me two rows:

```
SELECT 
DocList.DocListId, RegistrationDocList.RegistrationDocListId, Registration.RegistrationId 
FROM 
DocList INNER JOIN
RegistrationDocList ON DocList.DocListId = RegistrationDocList.DocListId INNER JOIN
Registration ON RegistrationDocList.RegistrationId = Registration.RegistrationId
WHERE (DocList.DocListId = 547)
```

Results:

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------
> DocListId   RegistrationDocListId    RegistrationId
> -------------------------------------------------------
> 547              097                     115
> 547              098                     116
> ```

UPDATE:

as you can see its using three tables, so i want to delete the rows from:

```
DocList where doclistid = 547
RegistrationDocList.RegistrationId  where RegistrationId in (097,098)
Registration.RegistrationId  where RegistrationId in (115,116)
```

Comment: These "rows" show data from different tables... what exactly is your question ?

Comment: Have you forgotten the rest of the question?

Comment: I see DocListId = 123 in your where condition, but 547 in results?

Comment: Which rows do you want to delete? Your query includes columns from `DocList`, `RegistrationDocList` and `Registration`. Please be more specific.

Comment: guys, i have updated my question, so what i want to do is to delete the rows from three different tables... hope it make sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cache the values to delete on the far side of the link table, delete the link records, and then delete the linked records:

```
DECLARE @reg_to_delete TABLE (id int)

INSERT INTO @reg_to_delete (id)
SELECT RegistrationID FROM RegistrationDocList WHERE DocListID = 547

DELETE FROM RegistrationDocList WHERE DocListID = 547

DELETE FROM RegistrationList WHERE RegistrationID IN (SELECT id FROM @reg_to_delete)

DELETE FROM DocList WHERE DocListID = 547
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed your point. I hope this code will help you:

```
DECLARE @Result int

BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY
        DELETE DocList where doclistid = 547
        DELETE RegistrationDocListwhere RegistrationId in (097,098)
        DELETE Registration where RegistrationId in (115,116)

        /* code was done properly => mark flag as OK */
        SET @Result = 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        /* some error occured => mark flag as ERROR */
        SET @Result = -1
    END CATCH

IF @Result = 0 BEGIN
    /* all is fine, transaction can be commited */
    COMMIT TRAN
END
ELSE BEGIN
    /* something is wrong, transaction must be rolled back */
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
```

Comment: Referential integrity is the issue here.  Order of tables to delete is important.

Comment: So, write the delete statements in right order. Where is the problem?

Comment: Just saying that your code as written will not work, as you won't be able to delete from `RegistrationDocList` before you delete from `Registration`, if he's got referential integrity going (and if he doesn't, he should).