# SQL Server data purge.Multiple delete statements

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a stored procedure to purge data from different tables. I've used multiple delete statements to delete the data from different table with the where condition. Is this a right approach?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/methods-of-speeding-up-a-huge-delete-from-table-with-no-clauses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to delete multiple rows in sp with one call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649810/efficient-way-to-delete-multiple-rows-in-sp-with-one-call)